# Java real time system sound detection

Tags: java, audio, detection

I want to write a program that can detect that a sound (anysound) came trough the default audio device.
When the detection occurs I want to turn the detection off for a second or two and make the program emulate two left clicks, before it the sound detection turns back on again.

Sofar I haven't found anything here in this topic, because usually people want to detect a specific sound which is way too hard to code.

Help would be really much apprechiated!

Comment: This question seems overly broad. You are basically asking "What framework should I use for audio processing in Java? In framework X, how I can read from the default input device? What signal processing techniques can be used to detect a sound? In framework X, how do I use signal processing technique Y? In framework X, how do I stop listening from an input device?" I think you are more likely to attract a good answer if you would ask these questions separately, and add your own research and relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down the problem:

1. get audio input working
2. sound detection working on the audio input
3. playback of clicks

There are several audio recording tutorials. Perhaps take [this example from CodeJava.net](https://www.codejava.net/coding/a-utility-for-recording-sound-in-java) as your source?

For sound detection, instead of shipping the stream to playback, as done in the tutorial, analyze it with a RMS (root-mean-square) algorithm. This first requires assembling the data into PCM. The exact code for that depends on the audio format. Once you have signed PCM, you can use the RMS method for monitoring the output level of the sound on the line.

Triggering the playback of a `Clip` with the desired recording would be one way to get your clicks. But if you can assemble PCM, you should be able to also write the PCM for an *impulse* signal on the left track and send that out on a `SourceDataLine`. An example of this in PCM would be a long chain of 0 values with a single frame of 1 in the sequence (where the PCM is signed floats ranging from -1 to 1). The "discontinuity" manifests as a click.

Example code for `Clip` and `SourceDataLine` can be found on the [javasound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) tag.

I hope there are enough keywords and terms here to help you find info for the various steps.